# Graphic issues with installing Ubuntu on PC with Radeon 7770

Tags: 14.04, ati, graphics, radeon, visual-artifacts

Haven't found anything about the issue I'm experiencing and would like someone to help me with it.
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04, but for some reason installation does load, but I get on monitor tiles of size 4px by 8px in zig-zag black/orange and can't see anything from them.

Managed somehow to get to select screen, but that is where issues start since I can't discern what option is what.

Anyone has idea how to fix it?

See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: It is sort of hard to capture screenshot during installation, but it looks something like this, only less visible. support.shindiristudio.com/downloads/Untitled-1.jpg

Comment: Probably GPU driver bug.

Comment: Well, I would not expect something like that on install... Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: Try booting with `nomodeset`. Or finish the install if that is possible, then install the proprietary drivers.

Comment: Well, it is my bad that I uploaded bad photo. Here you can see what is actually behind. On my install, it is simply not possible to see anything. Install starts well while loading, but starts with these tiles when "select" screen starts. Will try later with it and see where it leads to.

Comment: @bain Probably make your `nomodeset` solution as an answer? user292183 says it worked. That way, after user292183 accepts the answer, we will know its solved!

Answer (score 1):

Try booting with `nomodeset`. After installing, you can install the proprietary drivers which may help.  It would also help to get this fixed if you could file a bug for your problem at http://wiki.x.org/wiki/radeon/